# Are dragon spawns really random?

Tags: league-of-legends

Since the new drake system is out, I've done quite a lot of games. I'm not sure if I'm being paranoid or so, but it seems that drakes don't really spawn randomly, it seems there are some combinations, and each color seems not to have 25% chance of spawning (on 50 games or so I've had like 35% cloud drake).

Not to mention I often see 3 fire drake in a row (same for lot of people in my friends list ), or 2 cloud 2 mountain.

Are there any stats related to dragon spawn or some pattern to find out what drake will come or is it really and only RNG?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per GeneralMike's comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As said [here](http://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/gameplay-balance/a9gcgfzV-elemental-dragons-what-were-doing-and-why) by Meddler:

> Instead of the current 5-buff dragon system, we’re changing it to 4 different types of elemental dragons, each of which gives a different buff. The types and order of elemental dragon spawn are randomized (with some restrictions) and it’s possible to get multiple stacks of one element (e.g. 2 air dragon kills gives more movement speed than 1 air dragon kill). After 35 minutes, the dragons are replaced by an elder dragon, who gives a consistent buff of his own and amplifies existing buffs when killed.

The only restrictions are:

> 1. There are never more than 3 different elemental dragons in a match (so if you get 1 fire, 1 mountain, 1 cloud, the 4th dragon will be one
>      of those again and there won't be any water in that match).
> 2. A given elemental dragon will never appear more than 3 times in 1 match (so you'll never get 4 fire dragons in the same match)
>
>    ```
>                                                              -GeneralMike
>    ```

Edit: [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/4kp403/i_kill_100_dragons_to_test_the_spawn_rate_here/) is a Reddit post where someone killed 100 dragons and kept tabs on what types they were and more. Perhaps this is more like what you seek.

Comment: I thought some people would have find these out after this time, guess I'm gonna have to be more patient

Comment: Were you perhaps looking for something more like this? https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/4kp403/i_kill_100_dragons_to_test_the_spawn_rate_here/

Comment: Yeah, forgot reddit, these are the kind of stuff I was looking for but in a bigger scale and with more precise infos, but I guess noone knows except riot developers...

Comment: You can always try to hit them up on Twitter

Comment: The restrictions I'm aware of are: 
1) There are never more than 3 different elemental dragons in a match (so if you get 1 fire, 1 mountain, 1 cloud, the 4th dragon will be one of those again and there won't be any water in that match).
2) A given elemental dragon will never appear more than 3 times in 1 match (so you'll never get 4 fire dragons in the same match).

Comment: Nice one too GeneralMike, it's the kind of stuff i'm looking for! thanks

Comment: @RiddlerNewComer Once he added the restrictions, mark this as accepted answer. Because then it would be perfect and mentions everything you need to know about dragon spawns.